# Group Structure levels in an excel having 400000 lines hangs up the application

Tags: excel, vba, performance, freeze

I have one simple macro where I am grouping rows based on structure levels (1-8) i.e. creating outline. When I run macro on an excel having 76k lines it takes time but completes the task. But after that if lines increase running the macro hangs up excel and I have to kill the process from Task manager.

[image]

```
Sub GroupReport()

    'Define Variables
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LevelCol As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurrentLevel As Integer 'iterative counter'
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Set StartCell = Cells(5, 1)
    StartRow = StartCell.Row
    LevelCol = StartCell.Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' Cells.ClearOutline
    
    'inarr = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(LastRow, 19))

    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        CurrentLevel = Cells(i, LevelCol)
        Rows(i).Select
        For j = 1 To CurrentLevel - 1
            On Error Resume Next
            Selection.Rows.Group
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

I tried setting manual calculation and screen updating off to improve the performance but its not helping much. I tried to copy data to variable array but not able to understand how to loop through it.

I would really appreciate any suggestion/help to make this workable for excel with 4L and improve performance.

Comment: Why do you select the row each time? This creates unnecessary overhead.

Comment: As I was not able to group rows using 'With Range' we used select row..I tested just now- removed that Rows(i).Select and while grouping used Rows(i).Rows.Group instead of Selection.Rows.Group, may be some overhead might have decreased but still hangs up excel..

Answer (score 0):

I would limit the number of interactions with the Worksheet such as Select method,  actual number of rows instead of UsedRange.Rows.Count, and use array for faster processing. Here is some touch on your code.

Sub My2ndAdjOptimized()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim LevelCol As Long
Dim CurrentLevel As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim LevelArr As Variant

' Define the working sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Start the timer
Dim StartTime As Double
StartTime = Timer

StartRow = 5
LevelCol = 1
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LevelCol).End(xlUp).Row

' Read data into an array
LevelArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow, LevelCol), ws.Cells(LastRow, LevelCol)).Value

' Iterate over rows to group them
For i = 1 To UBound(LevelArr, 1)
    CurrentLevel = LevelArr(i, 1)
    For j = 1 To CurrentLevel - 1
        ws.Rows(StartRow + i - 1).Group
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' Display runtime
MsgBox "Runtime: " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) & " seconds"
```

End Sub

Comment: Hello @vbakim, Grateful for your efforts and suggestions...above code is optimizing the performance but when I am increasing my data to 1L or 1.5L lines it just endlessly shows not responding...My data has 3.7L lines originally but my or your macro code does not run even for 1.5L lines as per my testing,....Do you think there is any other logic I should apply?

Comment: I created a dummy table that has 10K rows and test my code. It works fine;
Here are the running time;
With No error resume: 17.36 sec.
Without : 9.3

Comment: Oh right not just for 10K, upto 95K row table it works fine, I was saying when rows are more than 0.1 Million (1 Lakh) or more, this does not complete the task of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I used the openpyxl library in Python to replicate the logic and noticed a significant improvement in speed. With a dataset of 400,000 rows, randomly assigning levels 1-8 in column A, the test file operation was finished in a mere 79.61 seconds without any issues.

Here is python code.

```
import openpyxl
from time import time

def group_rows_based_on_levels(filename):
    # Load workbook and select active sheet
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.active
    
    start_time = time()
    
    start_row = 5
    level_col = 1
    
    # Determine the last row with data in the level column
    last_row = ws.max_row

    for i in range(start_row, last_row + 1):
        current_level = ws.cell(row=i, column=level_col).value
        if current_level is not None:
            for _ in range(current_level - 1):
                ws.row_dimensions[i].outlineLevel += 1
                ws.row_dimensions[i].hidden = True

    # Save the changes
    wb.save(filename)
    
    runtime = round(time() - start_time, 2)
    print(f"Runtime: {runtime} seconds")

# Example usage
group_rows_based_on_levels("your_file.xlsx")
```